# Python: Printing two lists in a for loop

Tags: python

I have two lists.

```
one=["first","second"]
two=[1,2]
for o in one:
    for t in two:
        print(o)
        print(t)
```

and the output is:

```
first
1
first
2
second
1
second
2
```

Here is what the correct output should be:

```
first
1
2
second
1
2
```

There one more ,my professor has asked to print the output-

```
first
1
second
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
for o in one:
    print(o)
    for t in two:
        print(t)
```

So that you only print the string number once per time you run the inner loop.

EDIT:

you can do this:

```
both = zip(one, two)
for tup in both:
  for val in tup:
    print(val, end=' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one more thing- I have to do, is to print it in this format- 
`one
1
two
2`

Comment: @user5661083 edited, I think this is what you're looking for.  Read more about `zip()`, it's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
for o in one:
    print(o)
    for t in two:
        print(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a slight change.

```
    one=["first","second"]
    two=[1,2]
    for o in one:
        print(o)
        for t in two:
            print(t)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be this:

```
one=["first","second"]
two=[1,2]
for o in one:
    print(o)
    for t in two:
        print(t)
```